# SQLite function to insert date YYYY-MM-DD instead of YYYYMMDD

Tags: database, sqlite

I am getting value of date in format YYYYMMDD `19840907`. I am trying to write insert into SQLite table with function that convert date to format YYYY-MM-DD `1984-09-07`. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO
    my_table (date)
VALUES
    (DATE('19840907'));
```

It seems that I am still misunderstanding how convert functions in this documentations should work.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the string function `substr()` for the conversion and not the function `date()` which operates only on the valid (for SQLite) date format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`:

```
INSERT INTO
    my_table (date)
VALUES(
  substr('19840907', 1, 4) || '-' ||
  substr('19840907', 5, 2) || '-' ||
  substr('19840907', 7, 2) 
)
```